# SVG background image in IE9

Tags: css, svg, internet-explorer-9

I have a strange problem with svg images as background in Internet Explorer 9.

I tested following css rules:

```
background-image: url(./grad.svg);  /* local file */
background-image: url(http://127.0.0.1:7101/path/to/images/grad.png);
background-image: url(http://127.0.0.1:7101/path/to/images/grad.svg);
```

while the first two rules work great, the last one fails. With the F12 Developer Tools it shows `(Pending...)` for the svg image. Accessing the images directly with their url, they are shown correctly in IE9.

I checked all three rules in Opera and they worked.

So what is wrong with the last rule?

//edit

additionally I tested following rule:

```
background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxIDEiIHByZXNlcnZlQXNwZWN0UmF0aW89Im5vbmUiPgo8bGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQgaWQ9Imc1MjQiIGdyYWRpZW50VW5pdHM9InVzZXJTcGFjZU9uVXNlIiB4MT0iMCUiIHkxPSIwJSIgeDI9IjEwMCUiIHkyPSIxMDAlIj4KPHN0b3Agc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgb2Zmc2V0PSIwIi8+PHN0b3Agc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI0UzQTgyMCIgb2Zmc2V0PSIxIi8+CjwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CjxyZWN0IHg9IjAiIHk9IjAiIHdpZHRoPSIxIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEiIGZpbGw9InVybCgjZzUyNCkiIC8+Cjwvc3ZnPg==);
```

worked fine both in IE9 and Opera

//edit 2

I also did try the following:

```
background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Android-System-Architecture.svg);
```

it worked!?

Comment: Can you repeat this on JSFiddle?

Comment: ahm, not sure how to do that, with the images hosted on a local webserver?

Comment: Verify that your local webserver sends the correct mediatype for svg files, `image/svg+xml`.

Comment: checked for `image/svg` as it is stated [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WD-SVG-19990412/intro.html)

Comment: @ErikDahlström You are right. Changed from `image/svg` to `image/svg+xml`. If you add this as an answer, I will accept that.

Comment: @Angelo.Hannes note that http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WD-SVG-19990412/intro.html is an old working draft of SVG (working drafts are expected to change). Refer to a more stable version instead, e.g http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-SVG11-20110816/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your local webserver sends the correct mediatype for svg files, `image/svg+xml`.

Comment: This is interesting. Can you explain what makes a difference?

Comment: Presumably IE doesn't try to make sense of invalid mediatypes (in this particular scenario at least).

Comment: @chovy intranet based server? if so see http://stackoverflow.com/a/21703410/109374 (IE has some special setting that disables HTML5 and svg when browsing intranet sites)

Comment: @chovy I'd recommend that you post another question with that fiddle and the specific details for how to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I did. nobody has solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23643074/svg-image-wont-load-with-css-background-in-ie9