# SVG image doesn't work in CSS background in IE9

Tags: css, svg, background-image

I am unable to get SVG `background-image` to work in IE9 or IE10, is it possible? (IE11 is OK)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chovy/3abhj/1/

```
<input type="text" class="invalid">

.invalid {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    background: url(http://chovy.us.to/test/x.svg) no-repeat 0 -2px;
    background-size: 22px 22px;
}
```

`x.svg` is served with `image/svg+xml`.

Comment: SVG should work in IE9: http://caniuse.com/svg. Your code does work in IE11's *emulation* of IE9.

Comment: I wish I had *real* IE 9 installed so's I could help further. :(

Comment: doesn't work in IE10 either. IE11 is ok

Comment: Have you tried specifying `width` and `height` attributes (24px in your case) on the <svg> root element? It might be that IE9 doesn't size the svg according to `background-size`.

Comment: its `background-image`, there is no `<svg>` element. Or are you talking about inside the actual `image.svg` file? That would be hardcoding the size then, which means I can't reuse it for other sizes.

Comment: Yes, I meant inside the x.svg file, and yes you are correct about that being hardcoding the size (so I can't really recommend doing that, but it should make it work across all browsers). Another option is to serve IE9 and 10 something other than svg.

Comment: Thanks. I will probably do PNG fallback for IE9/10.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Background-size with SVG squished in IE9-10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21840551/background-size-with-svg-squished-in-ie9-10)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using this image **only** in `background-image` property (**not** in `<img>` tag), you could use fixed `width` and `height` attributes. It scales well in all popular browsers — [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/onzk8eaL/5/).

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24">
    <path fill="#C54C44" d="M17.5 7.4L16.1 6 12 10.1 7.9 6 6.5 7.4l4.1 4.1-4.1 4.1L7.9 17l4.1-4.1 4.1 4.1 1.4-1.4-4.1-4.1"/>
</svg>
```

```css
input {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;    
}

.invalid {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    background: url(http://imgh.us/x_1.svg) no-repeat 0 -2px;
    background-size: 22px 22px;
}

.invalid-large {
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: url(http://imgh.us/x_1.svg) no-repeat 0 -4px;
    background-size: 44px 44px;
}

.invalid-max {
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    background: url(http://imgh.us/x_1.svg) no-repeat 0 -6px;
    background-size: 66px 66px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="invalid">
<input type="text" class="invalid-large">
<input type="text" class="invalid-max">
```